# How to move from ASP .NET MVC DB first with EDMX to ASP .Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a Database first project using EDMX written in ASP.NET MVC 5. I want to move to ASP .NET core 3.1.

What would be the best way to go about since it does not seem like .Net Core still supports EDMX's?

Comment: DB First hasn't needed an EDMX model since at least EF 4. You can reverse engineer a database directly into a DbContext and entities

Answer (score 0):

There is no edmx support in Entity Framework Core. It only supports a code-first approach.
Use the following command to create code-first models for your existing database.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=.\SQLEXPRESS;Database=SchoolDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -o Models
```

Answer (score 0):

Install "EF Core Power Tools" for Visual Studio and use "Reverse Engineering" option of this tools to create EF core code-first code from your existing database.